# Capybara save_and_open_page ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, ubuntu, capybara

I am running Ubunut 13.04, and Rubymine 6.0.3

My problem is that  Launchy gem isn't opening my browser.

I debuged Capybara save_and_open_page and executed

```
Launchy.open(file_name,{debug:true})
```

The html page is saved, however the browser doesn't launch.

This was the debug result

```
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: URI parsing pass 1 : /home/dave/my_i/tmp/capybara/capybara-201401200000077817027890.html -> {:scheme=>nil, :user=>nil, :password=>nil, :host=>nil, :port=>nil, :path=>"/home/dave/my_i/tmp/capybara/capybara-201401200000077817027890.html", :query=>nil, :fragment=>nil}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: URI parsing pass 2 : /home/dave/my_i/tmp/capybara/capybara-201401200000077817027890.html -> {:scheme=>nil, :user=>nil, :password=>nil, :host=>nil, :port=>nil, :path=>"/home/dave/my_i/tmp/capybara/capybara-201401200000077817027890.html", :query=>nil, :fragment=>nil}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Checking if class Launchy::Application::Browser is the one for handles?(/home/dave/my_i/tmp/capybara/capybara-201401200000077817027890.html)}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Checking if class Launchy::Detect::HostOsFamily::Windows is the one for matches?(linux-gnu)}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Checking if class Launchy::Detect::HostOsFamily::Darwin is the one for matches?(linux-gnu)}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Checking if class Launchy::Detect::HostOsFamily::Nix is the one for matches?(linux-gnu)}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Checking if class Launchy::Detect::RubyEngine::Mri is the one for is_current_engine?(ruby)}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Checking if class Launchy::Detect::HostOsFamily::Windows is the one for matches?(linux-gnu)}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Checking if class Launchy::Detect::HostOsFamily::Darwin is the one for matches?(linux-gnu)}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Checking if class Launchy::Detect::HostOsFamily::Nix is the one for matches?(linux-gnu)}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Checking if class Launchy::Detect::RubyEngine::Mri is the one for is_current_engine?(ruby)}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Checking if class Launchy::Detect::NixDesktopEnvironment::Kde is the one for is_current_desktop_environment?()}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Checking if class Launchy::Detect::NixDesktopEnvironment::Gnome is the one for is_current_desktop_environment?()}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Launchy::Application : Unable to find `gnome-open' in /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@myi/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/bin, /usr/local/heroku/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin, /usr/local/sbin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/sbin, /usr/bin, /sbin, /bin, /usr/games, /usr/local/games, /home/dave/JSMS
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Launchy::Application : found executable /usr/bin/firefox
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Launchy::Application : Unable to find `seamonkey' in /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@myi/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/bin, /usr/local/heroku/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin, /usr/local/sbin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/sbin, /usr/bin, /sbin, /bin, /usr/games, /usr/local/games, /home/dave/JSMS
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Launchy::Application : Unable to find `opera' in /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@myi/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/bin, /usr/local/heroku/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin, /usr/local/sbin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/sbin, /usr/bin, /sbin, /bin, /usr/games, /usr/local/games, /home/dave/JSMS
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Launchy::Application : Unable to find `mozilla' in /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@myi/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/bin, /usr/local/heroku/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin, /usr/local/sbin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/sbin, /usr/bin, /sbin, /bin, /usr/games, /usr/local/games, /home/dave/JSMS
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Launchy::Application : Unable to find `netscape' in /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@myi/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/bin, /usr/local/heroku/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin, /usr/local/sbin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/sbin, /usr/bin, /sbin, /bin, /usr/games, /usr/local/games, /home/dave/JSMS
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Launchy::Application : Unable to find `galeon' in /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@myi/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/bin, /usr/local/heroku/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin, /usr/local/sbin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/sbin, /usr/bin, /sbin, /bin, /usr/games, /usr/local/games, /home/dave/JSMS
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Launchy::Application::Browser : possibility from app_list : firefox
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Checking if class Launchy::Detect::NixDesktopEnvironment::Kde is the one for is_current_desktop_environment?()}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Checking if class Launchy::Detect::NixDesktopEnvironment::Gnome is the one for is_current_desktop_environment?()}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Launchy::Application : Unable to find `gnome-open' in /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@myi/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/bin, /usr/local/heroku/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin, /usr/local/sbin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/sbin, /usr/bin, /sbin, /bin, /usr/games, /usr/local/games, /home/dave/JSMS
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Launchy::Application : found executable /usr/bin/firefox
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Launchy::Application : Unable to find `seamonkey' in /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@myi/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/bin, /usr/local/heroku/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin, /usr/local/sbin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/sbin, /usr/bin, /sbin, /bin, /usr/games, /usr/local/games, /home/dave/JSMS
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Launchy::Application : Unable to find `opera' in /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@myi/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/bin, /usr/local/heroku/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin, /usr/local/sbin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/sbin, /usr/bin, /sbin, /bin, /usr/games, /usr/local/games, /home/dave/JSMS
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Launchy::Application : Unable to find `mozilla' in /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@myi/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/bin, /usr/local/heroku/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin, /usr/local/sbin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/sbin, /usr/bin, /sbin, /bin, /usr/games, /usr/local/games, /home/dave/JSMS
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Launchy::Application : Unable to find `netscape' in /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@myi/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/bin, /usr/local/heroku/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin, /usr/local/sbin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/sbin, /usr/bin, /sbin, /bin, /usr/games, /usr/local/games, /home/dave/JSMS
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Launchy::Application : Unable to find `galeon' in /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@myi/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/bin, /usr/local/heroku/bin, /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin, /usr/local/sbin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/sbin, /usr/bin, /sbin, /bin, /usr/games, /usr/local/games, /home/dave/JSMS
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Launchy::Application::Browser : Using browser value 'firefox'
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.22, debase 0.0.9) listens on 127.0.0.1:49751
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: wet_run: before exec in child process
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: commandline_normalized => firefox /home/dave/my_i/tmp/capybara/capybara-201401200000077817027890.html

(process:18970): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
```

Weird thing is it looks like it's finding firefox, however my default browser is chrome

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

This returns

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative x-www-browser (providing /usr/bin/x-www-browser).

  Selection    Path                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/firefox                40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       manual mode
```

The other weird thing, it looks like firefox is running (in system monitor I see the process)
However I don't have any firefox window and when i try to start firefox I get the error

```
Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your system
```

So a few issues here

a) I expected Launchy to be using chrome not firefox

b) Firefox process doesn't seem to start correctly (however I can start firefox normally otherwise)

Comment: I think I'll manage to find a way to resolve the issue with the FF but I would appreciate if you can tell me how I can get same `LAUNCHY_DEBUG` log.

Comment: how did you resolve your FF issue?, I used RubyMine debugger and stepped into save_and_open_page and and executed Launchy.open({debug:true}) to get the logs

Comment: it gets resolved by itself somehow (maybe after restart) so there's not much I can troubleshoot now. But I was thinking of [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#Remote_Control)